# How to install fonts?

Tags: nsis

If I just use **File** to install fonts, installation goes fine, but the fonts are useless: no characters show up when you try to write with them, and if you doubleclick them in a fonts folder, their preview would be blank.

So far I tried to follow [this guide](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Register_Fonts), with this snippet of code:

```
FindFirst $5 $6 "..\3rdparty\fonts\*.ttf"
loop:
    StrCmp $6 "" done
    !insertmacro InstallTTFFont $6
    FindNext $5 $6
    Goto loop
done:
FindClose $5
```

However, I get this error:

> !insertmacro: InstallTTFFont Push: $0
>   Push: $R0 Push: $R1 Push: $R2 !define:
>   "Index"="Line66.6" !insertmacro:
>   GetFileNameCall Push: $6 Call
>   "GetFileName" Pop: $0 !insertmacro:
>   end of GetFileNameCall !define:
>   "FontFileName"="$0" SetOutPath:
>   "$FONT_DIR" IfFileExists:
>   "$FONT_DIR\$0" ? Line66.6 :  File:
>   "$6" -> no files found. Usage: File
>   [/nonfatal] [/a] ([/r] [/x filespec
>   [...]] filespec [...] |
>   /oname=outfile one_file_only) Error in
>   macro InstallTTFFont on macroline 14
>   Error in script
>   "C:\ScanModule\Install\ScanModule.nsi"
>   on line 66 -- aborting creation
>   process

**Edit:** If I just manually write out all of the individual fonts, it works. So problem solved. Sorta. Not that I'm complaining, but that's not cool.

Comment: Well, its a wiki, there is nothing stopping you from contributing a version of the macro that only registers the font...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 4 thoughts about it:

1. Did you try also quotes?

   !insertmacro InstallTTFFont "$6"
2. Is FindFirst ... loop performed on developer's machine or on user's machine? I am not sure how it works and if implementation fits to you.
3. I see you use relative path "..\3rdparty\fonts*.ttf". What is working directory in time you launched the command?
4. You could also add something like this into the C:\ScanModule\Install\ScanModule.nsi to understand why only manually wrote fonts work.

   MessageBox MB_OK "Param 0: $0"